# NullPointerException on getStreamMaxVolume

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-audiomanager

I have the following line of code:

```
final int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
```

For which I am receiving the following warning on the "getStreamMaxVolume" keyword in Android Studio:

"Method invocation 'getStreamMaxVolume' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'"

Would anyone know how to resolve this warning?

Comment: that means `audioManager` might be null so keep a null check around the call

Comment: add try catch block to your code snippet

Comment: Thank you to both of you. Actually, I was wondering why Android Studio was generating this warning on the getStreamMaxVolume keyword, but not on other keywords such as getStreamVolume found in similar statements for example. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You get the warning message because the method, `getStreamMaxVolume()` sometimes throws the null pointer exception. So, in order to make the warning go away, you have to handle the Exception like this.

```
try
{
     final int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
}
catch(java.lang.NullPointerException exception)
{
     //how you want to handle the exception
}
```

Comment: Actually, would you know why Android Studio generates this warning on the getStreamMaxVolume keyword, but not on other keywords such as getStreamVolume found in similar statements for example?

Comment: @JF0001 it should though. Because if the audioManager becomes null, how can we call either method? But if it doesn't, I have no idea why. I'll look into it. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(audioManager!=null){
   final int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
}
```

keep a check around the call for `null` check